# Spring cloud stream functional producer/consumer bean is not working when declared out side of @SpringBootApplication

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

if userProducer is placed in a separate class, it is not getting triggered, for example via StreamBridge.

```
package com.moments.auth;

import com.moments.auth.payload.UserEventPayload;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.EnableBinding;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

@SpringBootApplication
public class AuthApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AuthApplication.class, args);
    }


    @Bean
    public Function<UserEventPayload, UserEventPayload> userProducer(){
        return userEventPayload -> {
            return userEventPayload;
        };
    }

}
```

**YAML file**

```
  cloud:
    stream:
      function:
        definition: userProducer
      bindings:
        userProducer-out-0:
          destination: user
      kafka.binder:
        brokers: 127.0.0.1
        defaultBrokerPort: 9092
```

Placing in separate class

```
package com.moments.auth.messaging;


import com.moments.auth.payload.UserEventPayload;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import java.util.function.Function

@Component
@Slf4j
public class UserEventSender {

    @Bean
    public Function<UserEventPayload, UserEventPayload> userProducer(){
        return userEventPayload -> {
            return userEventPayload;
        };
    }

}
```

what should I need to do if userProducer binding needs to work if its place out of the main class?

Update-1 added the package names

Comment: It has to be in the same package (or a sub package) as the main application, or you need to specify which packages to look for `@Component`s in with a `@ComponentScan`.

Answer (score 0):

You defined a `Function` bean, which means that your application is now a `processor` (`Supplier` for `Source` and `Consumer` for `Sink`).

A `Processor` will receive messages from a input binding topic, process them and put it down to a output binding topic (userProducer-out-0.destination=user in your case)

---

You need to define a `input binding`, for example:

```
bindings:
    userProducer-in-0:
      destination: inputTopic
      group: groupTest
    userProducer-out-0:
      destination: user
```

---

Your `UserEventSender` class belongs to `com.moments.auth.messaging` package which is a sub package of your main class `com.moments.auth`. It's ok now and will be scanned by `@ComponentScan` in `@SpringBootApplication`.

Comment: You mean that: With your current YAML file and `Function` userProducer() in AuthApplication, when you produced a message to `userProducer-in-0` topic (the topic name was auto-generated because you didn't explicitly declare it in YAML), everything seemed to work, don't you?

Comment: here topic name is "user" , yes if function userProducer is in authApplication then there is no issue, another consumer listening on the same topic("user") in another micro service was able to get the message, but function userProducer is placed in UserEventSender  then its not working as expected

Comment: when I said `Function` userProducer(), I meant `java.util.function.Function` userProducer(). From what you said and your YAML file, I think you were defining `java.util.function.Suplier` userProducer(), and this `Supplier` through your YAML configuration will produce message to 'user' `topic`.

Comment: I will provide the repo link, for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You `UserEventSender` is annotated with `@Component` instead of `@Configuration`.

While `@Configuration` is also a `@Component` (for component scanning purposes), `@Component` is not `@Configuration` as it implies a single component.

Comment: i have even tried that approach, but still its not working.